# Visualforce + Angular JS, ui-router not working

Tags: visualforce, angular

I've been doing some digging to figure out how I can get ui-router to work. I came across this:

> [How can I reference angularjs template files within a visualforce page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28498/how-can-i-reference-angularjs-template-files-within-a-visualforce-page)

but every answer on there didn't work for me.

Here's the VF page:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" docType="html-5.0">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.QuarryResources, 'app/css/style.css')}" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html ng-app="quarryApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></meta>
        <meta name="description" content=""></meta>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css"></link>
        <base href="{!URLFOR($Resource.QuarryResources, 'app/')}" />
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    </head>
    <body ng-app="quarryApp">
```

I've uploaded the related resources as a .zip in the Static Resources of my sandbox; here's the structure:

```
QuarryResources.zip
  - app
    - css
    - images
    - script
    - pages
```

Here's what a sample partial loos like:

```
<section class = "main-wrapper">
  <header ng-model="message">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </header>
</section>
```

Controller for QuarryApp:

```
var quarryApp = angular.module('quarryApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl: "pages/home.html"
      });
  });
```

If possible, I'd like to go down the route of storing the partials as a static resource rather than as visualforce pages. My research has shown that the performance is much faster that way; of course, correct me if I'm wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated by this new VF and Angular developer.

Regards,
W

Comment: Oh I forgot to add, if possible, I'd like to go down the route of storing the partials as a static resource rather than as visualforce pages. My research has shown that the performance is much faster that way; of course, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Probably best you solve your current problem first. But once you have, I would strongly recommend that you use static resources for your partials rather than pages. Here is how [Serving AngularJS templates from static resources](http://force201.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/serving-angularjs-templates-from-static-resources/).

Comment: @KeithC, that's actually what I'm trying to do. You'll see my partials are in the .zip file that is uploaded into Static Resources. I just named them pages instead of partials.

Comment: Sorry only glanced at your question.

Comment: @keithC, no problem. I think I've hit a wall, would you be able to help me? greenstork helped me figure how to set up ui-router on visualforce but the partials are still not showing up...

Comment: Its nearly midnight here so not today. Your browser's developer tools are you friend for this sort of work to see what is going wrong.

Comment: @KeithC, let me know if you're available, I'm still scratching my head on this... 

Almost ready to give up on Angular partials and go with <apex: include>

Comment: Have you reviewed this complete sample Angular app https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/IssuesInGitHub: provides a good working example to start from.

Comment: Let me check that out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @KeithC, after fiddling with this for 4 hours, still no progress. Console isn't showing any errors either. I've hit a wall.

If you are available the help, I'd greatly appreciate your expertise on this matter.

Comment: A few comments sure, but digging in to someone else's code base is not something I want to do. All I can suggest is you get the non-minified version of all the JavaScript and use your browser's breakpoints etc to see where it all goes wrong. That's a great way to learn about how to write good JavaScript too as you'll be looking at Angular's code.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML in you Angular app is no longer relative to the VF page, so you need to figure out the base path through some trickery. You can do this by creating a simple module in your VF page, in a script tag, which stores the path of your static resource in an angular constant, like so:

```
<script>
    "use strict";
    angular.module('server-data', [])
      .constant('basePath', '{!URLFOR($Resource.hubApps, "")}'.split('?')[0]);
</script>
```

You would then need to include that module in your app dependencies and use the base path whenever referencing template URLs.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out!

I'm having some difficulty understanding your answer

I added the module in the <head> of my VF page, but I'm not too sure on how to go about 'including that module in my app dependencies and use the base path whenever referencing template URLs.

Comment: Does it look something like this:

`var quarryApp = angular.module('quarryApp', ['ui.router', 'server-data'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl: "pages/home.html"
      });
  });`

Sorry about the formatting, line breaks isn't working for some odd reason...

Comment: close, you'd need to add basePath to your .config function and reference it in your templateUrl

Comment: greenstork, does this look right to you?  

`  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $basePath) {`

and when I reference it in my template Url, did you mean like this?

`      .state('home', {  
        url:'/home',  
        templateUrl: "basePath/pages/home.html"  
      });`

Comment: Oh and I just tried adding that module to my VF page and it's saying: Error: Static Resource named hubApps does not exist. Check spelling.

I take it I was supposed to replace hubApps with Quarry Resources, right?

Comment: Yeah, this was my example from my code, you should reference your static resource

Comment: Weird, I added basePath to the config function, and now none of the javascript/jquery work: 

`.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $basePath) {`

Comment: try basePath, not $basePath

Comment: var quarryApp = angular.module('quarryApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, basePath) {

yields the same results.

Comment: In the last example you've provided (unlike the first comment), server-data is not included in the app dependencies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16087/discussion-between-codemky-and-greenstork).

Comment: Let me know if you can help me still, the partials aren't showing up even though the console isn't throwing an error...